# #Err: Cant connect to MySQl server on '192.168.0.114' ((10060) MySQL error code 2003

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, wamp

I am trying to connect to MySQL database remotely,.
my connection string is
con = driver->connect("tcp://192.168.0.114:3306/","root","");
and i am developing my project on VC++.
and error is

## Err: Cant connect to MySQl server on '192.168.0.114' ((10060) MySQL error code 2003

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be that a firewall is blocking your request.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html:

The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Comment: This is 10060, not 10061. I believe that means it is impossible to reach the server from an outside connection.